# compare strings returned from function calls

Tags: c++, string, oop

I can not seem to figure out why the get_password function call will always return qwert no matter what string I pass into the function. My problem is that I can not see what is going wrong with the string comparison in this function.

```
string get(string askfor, int numchars, string input)
{
    cout << askfor << "(" << numchars << " characters): ";
    cin >> input;
    return input;
}

string get_password(string name)
{
    string pwd;
    if (name == "botting"){
        pwd = "123456";
    }
    else if (name == "ernesto") {
        pwd = "765432";
    }
    else if (name == "tong") {
        pwd = "234567";
    }
    else {
        pwd = "qwert";
    }

    return pwd;
}

int main()
{
    string name;
    string pwd;
    string passwd;
    cout << "Address of name =" << &name << "\n";
    cout << "Address of pwd =" << &pwd << "\n";
    cout << "Address of passwd =" << &passwd << "\n";

    bool authenticated = false;
    while (!authenticated)
    {
        // call one 
        string name1 = get("Name", 7, name);
        cout << "call one returned: " << name1 << endl;

        // call two
        string pass1 = get_password(name);
        cout << "call two returned: " << pass1 << endl;

        //call three
        string pass2 = get("Password", 7, passwd);
        cout << "call three returned: " << pass2 << endl;

        // compare the two passwords
        authenticated = false;
        if (pass1 == pass2) {
            cout << "Welcome " << name << "\n";
            authenticated = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please try again\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code confuses `name1` with `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `name1` to the second call:

```
    // call one 
    string name1 = get("Name", 7, name);
    cout << "call one returned: " << name1 << endl;

    // call two
    string pass1 = get_password(name1); // change this variable
    cout << "call two returned: " << pass1 << endl;
```

the `get()` returns the name to `name1` string and does not update `name` variable itself, because of this `name` remains empty string.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never assign `name` anything. It is initialized as `""`, and that never changes. Since that matches none of the cases in `get_password`, it always falls into the `else` case, which yields `"qwert"`.

I think the issue is that your `get` function would be better written like:

```
string get(string askfor, int numchars)
{
    string input; // input shouldn't be an argument
    cout << askfor<<"("<<numchars<<" characters): ";
    cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```

And you can use the *result* of that to assign into `name`:

```
name = get("Name", 7);
```

Comment: I tried declaring name inside the function and assigning that but the program still falls down the the last else statement                              string get_password(string nameParam)
{
 string pwd;
 string name = nameParam;
 if(name == "botting"){
  pwd = "123456";
 }
 else if (name == "ernesto") {
  pwd = "765432";
 }
 else if (name == "tong") {
  pwd = "234567";
 }
 else {
  pwd = "qwert";
 }
 return pwd;
}

Comment: @MbusiHlatshwayo Did you try my suggestion? And then call `get_password(name)`? Print the value of `name` before you call `get_password` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass by **reference** rather than **value**.

```
string get(string askfor, int numchars, string &input)
{
    cout << askfor << "(" << numchars << " characters): ";
    cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```